# Extraer valores de array

Tags: javascript

Tengo tres array de objetos  , necesito extraer un solo dato de cada objeto en cada uno de los arrays y exponerlos en párrafos diferentes en un documento html. Lamentablemente me imprime varias veces cada dato .
Uno de los array es :

```
let objDos = {
    Dental: [
      {
          HORA: "8:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ANDREA ZUÑIGA",
          PACIENTE: "MARCELA RETAMAL",
          RUT: "11123425-6",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PIA ZAÑARTU",
          PACIENTE: "ANGEL MUÑOZ",
          RUT: "9878789-2",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "SCARLETT WITTING",
          PACIENTE: "MARIO KAST",
          RUT: "7998789-5",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "FRANCISCO VON TEUBER",
          PACIENTE: "KARIN FERNANDEZ",
          RUT: "18887662-K",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "EDUARDO VIÑUELA",
          PACIENTE: "HUGO SANCHEZ",
          RUT: "17665461-4",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "14:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "RAQUEL VILLASECA",
          PACIENTE: "ANA SEPULVEDA",
          RUT: "14441281-0",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      }
    ]
    }
```

A este array , aplico el siguiente código

```
let array = objDos.Dental;
    for(item of array){
        let paragraph = []
        for(let value in item){
            paragraph.push(item.PACIENTE);
        }
       console.log(paragraph);
    }
```

Pero en la consola del navegador me devuelve

```
(5) ["MARCELA RETAMAL", "MARCELA RETAMAL", "MARCELA RETAMAL", "MARCELA RETAMAL", "MARCELA RETAMAL"]
VM457:54 (5) ["ANGEL MUÑOZ", "ANGEL MUÑOZ", "ANGEL MUÑOZ", "ANGEL MUÑOZ", "ANGEL MUÑOZ"]
VM457:54 (5) ["MARIO KAST", "MARIO KAST", "MARIO KAST", "MARIO KAST", "MARIO KAST"]
VM457:54 (5) ["KARIN FERNANDEZ", "KARIN FERNANDEZ", "KARIN FERNANDEZ", "KARIN FERNANDEZ", "KARIN FERNANDEZ"]
VM457:54 (5) ["HUGO SANCHEZ", "HUGO SANCHEZ", "HUGO SANCHEZ", "HUGO SANCHEZ", "HUGO SANCHEZ"]
VM457:54 (5) ["ANA SEPULVEDA", "ANA SEPULVEDA", "ANA SEPULVEDA", "ANA SEPULVEDA", "ANA SEPULVEDA"]
undefined
```

A diferencia de eso lo que yo busco es

```
Marcela retamal
Angel Muñoz
Mario Kast
Karin Fernandez
Hugo Sanchez
Ana Sepulveda
```

Luego replicar esto en tres arreglos más y llevar este resultado a un documento html , por medio del uso del método innerHTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en el código.

- Defines la variable paragraph dentro de un ciclo, con lo que se definirá varias veces, pero al final, quieres que *acumule* los valores, con lo que debieras definirla una sola vez, fuera del ciclo.
- Dado que solo quieres recuperar el paciente de cada elemento del arreglo, solo tienes que recorrer el array para extraerlo directamente, no hace falta que recorras sus atributos (recuerda que quieres un único atributo de cada objeto).
- Al igual que la declaración de la variable, la impresión debiera ocurrir una única vez, luego de terminar de recorrer el arreglo. Tú estás mandándolo a imprimir muchas veces, una por cada iteración del ciclo.

Corrigiendo esos problemas, el código luciría algo como:

```js
let objDos = {
    Dental: [
      {
          HORA: "8:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ANDREA ZUÑIGA",
          PACIENTE: "MARCELA RETAMAL",
          RUT: "11123425-6",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PIA ZAÑARTU",
          PACIENTE: "ANGEL MUÑOZ",
          RUT: "9878789-2",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "SCARLETT WITTING",
          PACIENTE: "MARIO KAST",
          RUT: "7998789-5",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "FRANCISCO VON TEUBER",
          PACIENTE: "KARIN FERNANDEZ",
          RUT: "18887662-K",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "EDUARDO VIÑUELA",
          PACIENTE: "HUGO SANCHEZ",
          RUT: "17665461-4",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "14:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "RAQUEL VILLASECA",
          PACIENTE: "ANA SEPULVEDA",
          RUT: "14441281-0",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      }
    ]
    }

let paragraph = []
let array = objDos.Dental;
for(item of array){
  paragraph.push(item.PACIENTE);
}
console.log(paragraph);
```

Dale clic al botón *"Ejecutar"* para probarlo aquí mismo en el navegador.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta . Ha sido de una gran ayuda

Answer (score 2):

**¿Qué tal?**

Su array *paragraph* se llenará/repetirá 6 veces por los objetos en su array *Dental* al estar en el bucle (for). Además, podría evitar variables de acceso, vacías y múltiples iteraciones tediosas.

Simplificando, propongo la siguiente solución con *ES8/ES6*, un poco más limpio y simple de entender para lograr lo que busca, obteniendo el mismo resultado.

```
const pacientes = Object.values(objDos['Dental']).map(pac => pac.PACIENTE)
console.log(pacientes)
```

`Object.values` devuelve los valores propios de una propiedad como una matriz, para este caso obtendrá los valores de los objetos accediendo directamente a *Dental* y `map` se encargará de filtrar las keys *PACIENTE* retornando sus valores en un nuevo array.

Comment: En este caso además debes explicarle al OP como y para que funciona map() y como haces la asignación del mismo. Por que como ves, lo que el tiene, no es problema obteniendo los datos, sino el cómo está aplicando la lógica para hacerlo, dado que ha iniciado e impreso valores dentro del array. (TLDR, vamos que solo le dices que es mejor hacerlo asi, pero no has marcado sus errores en SU codigo)